# Trying to merge sort a linked list and getting a stackoverflow exception. How might I prevent that?

Tags: c#, linked-list, stack-overflow, computer-science, mergesort

```
class MultiLinkedListOfBooks
{
    Book firstAuthor = null;

    private class Book
    {
        private string author, title;
        private double price;
        public Book next;
        public char authorchar, titlechar;
        public Book(string author1, string title1, double price1)
        {
            price = price1;
            title = title1;
            author = author1;
            next = null;
            string[] authorsplit = author.Split(null);
            authorchar = (authorsplit[1].Substring(0, 1).ToLower())[0];
            titlechar = (title.Substring(0, 1).ToLower())[0];
            Console.WriteLine(authorchar + "   " + titlechar);
        }
        // This compares 'this' book to the other book's author and title.
        // This version FIRST compares by author, and if they're the same THEN compares by title
        //done
        public int CompareAuthorTHENTitle(string otherBooksAuthor, string otherBooksTitle)
        {
            if (author.Equals(otherBooksAuthor))
            {
                if (title.Equals(otherBooksTitle))
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }

        // This compares 'this' book to the other book's author and title.
        // This version FIRST compares by title, and if they're the same THEN compares by author
        public int CompareTitleTHENAuthor(string otherBooksAuthor, string otherBooksTitle)
        {   // You may (or may not) need this method
            return 0;
        }
        //done
        // Print out the book info (author, title, price).
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Author: " + author);
            Console.WriteLine("Title: " + title);
            Console.WriteLine("Price: " + price);
        }
    }
    //done
    public ErrorCode Add(string author, string title, double price)
    {
        bool end = false;
        Book temp = firstAuthor;
        if (temp == null)
        {
            firstAuthor = new Book(author, title, price);
            return ErrorCode.OK;
        }
        if (temp.next == null) end = true;
        while (end == false)
        {
            if (temp.CompareAuthorTHENTitle(author, title) == 1)
            {
                return ErrorCode.DuplicateBook;
            }

            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = new Book(author, title, price);
        firstAuthor = sort(firstAuthor);
        return ErrorCode.OK;
        // having multiple books with the same author, but different titles, or 
        // multiple books with the same title, but different authors, is fine.

        // two books with the same author & title should be identified as duplicates,
        // even if the prices are different.
    }

    public void PrintByAuthor()
    {
        // if there are no books, then print out a message saying that the list is empty
        if (firstAuthor == null) Console.WriteLine("There are no books!");
        else
        {
            Book temp = firstAuthor;
            bool end = false;
            while (end == false)
            {
                temp.Print();
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (temp.next == null) end = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //done
    public ErrorCode Remove(string author, string title)
    {
        // if there isn't an exact match, then do the following:
        if (firstAuthor == null) return ErrorCode.BookNotFound;
        Book temp = firstAuthor;
        Book before = null;
        bool end = false;
        while (end == false)
        {
            if (temp.CompareAuthorTHENTitle(author, title) == 1)
            {
                if (before == null)
                {
                    firstAuthor = temp.next;
                }
                else
                {
                    before.next = temp.next;
                }
            }
            before = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
            if (temp.next == null) return ErrorCode.BookNotFound;
        }
        return ErrorCode.BookNotFound;
        // (this includes finding a book by the given author, but with a different title,
        // or a book with the given title, but a different author)
    }
    private Book sort(Book node)
    {
        if (firstAuthor == null && firstAuthor.next == null) return node;
        Book merge(Book a, Book b)
                {
                    Book result;
                    if (a == null) return b;
                    if (b == null) return a;
                    if (a.authorchar == b.authorchar)
                    {
                        if (a.titlechar <= b.titlechar && a.authorchar == b.authorchar)
                        {
                            result = a;
                            result.next = merge(a.next, b);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = b;
                            result.next = merge(a, b.next);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (a.authorchar < b.authorchar)
                    {
                        result = a;
                        result.next = merge(a.next, b);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = b;
                        result.next = merge(a, b.next);
                    }
                    return result;
                }
        Book middle(Book top)
                {
                    if (top == null) return top;
                    Book slow = top;
                    Book fast = top;
                    while (fast.next != null && fast.next.next != null)
                    {
                        slow = slow.next;
                        fast = fast.next.next;
                        fast = slow.next;
                    }
                    return slow;
                }
        Book mid = middle(node);
        Book l = node;
        Book r = mid.next;
        mid.next = null;
        return merge(sort(l), sort(r));
    }
}
```

Above is my code. I get the exception on the "Book mid = middle(node);" line. To give some context the book class has a few fields, the two important ones being author and title. Merge checks author then title to determine how it merges to sort alphabetically first by author then by name. This is all to sort the Book objects alphabetically by author first and then name in the LinkedList. As the title says, I am getting the stackoverflow exception and cannot figure out a way to avoid necessarily.

EDIT: Added code context. Doing this for a cs project where the requirements of the node are:

Has fields for author, title, price

Has print method

Has constructor

[How the Linked List is supposed to be modeled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziz4q.jpg)

Comment: `fast = fast.next.next; fast = slow.next;` um, that cannot be right? Only the last statement will have any effect, unless `next` has side effects, which it **really** shouldn't. `Book`s are not nodes, there should not be a `Book#next`. Maybe nodes store references to books in a list implementation, but that's something different.

Comment: My post has been updated.

Comment: The first line of defense against `StackOverflowException` is to make sure your code doesn't have bugs that would lead to infinite recursion. Once you've established that the code is correct, if there it is still overflowing the stack, then you need to take steps to reduce the recursive depth, or eliminate it altogether. See marked duplicate. ...

Comment: ... If you are having trouble finding and fixing bugs in your code, post a new question and this time make sure it includes a [mcve]. Also, it would be better if the [mcve] were designed to demonstrate a problem _before_ the `StackOverflowException` itself. This will aid and simplify debugging.

Comment: @JakeTheSteak - your post may have been updated, but it still has the problem line of code `fast = slow.next;` .